# ASP.NET Html.DropList Действие при выборе значения из списка

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

привет есть код.

```
@Html.DropDownList("sort", new SelectList(new string[]
                                              {
                                                "Автор ", "Цена убыв. ", "Цена воз. ", "Год выпуска "
                                              }),new { @class = "sort"})
```

как обработать событие выбора элемента из списка.
Выбрал элемент из списка и идет запрос  в контролер и потом к методу в этом контролере. Как то так.
Я вижу это так. Я выбрал значение потом идет вывоз метода из контролера. В методе идет запрос в бд в котором возвращаются значение отсортированные через SQL запрос и уже  в отсортированном виде возвращаются во вьюшку.
До это у меня абсолютно все вьюшки подгружалось через Ajax

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("text", "имя метода", new { передаваемый параметр в метод }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "book" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList("sort", new SelectList(new List<ListItem> { 
    new ListItem { Text = "Автор ", Value = "0" }, 
    new ListItem { Text = "Цена убыв. ", Value = "1", 
    new ListItem { Text = "Цена воз. ", Value = "2", 
    new ListItem { Text = "Год выпуска ", Value = "3" }
}),new { @class = "sort", @id="ddlsort"}},
new { @onchange="CallChangefunc(this.value)" })

<script>
function CallChangefunc(val)
{
    window.location.href="/Controller/Actionmethod?value="+val;
}
</script>
```

Через **Ajax**

```
$(document).on('change', '#ddlsort', function () {
    /*POST*/
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Actionmethod',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { передаваемый параметр в метод, пример: value: $("#ddlsort").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            /*код*/
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: как это через Ajax сделать. или это  не будет страницу перезагружать?

Comment: Добавил коды Ajax

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("sort", new SelectList(new string[]
                                              {
                                                "Автор ", "Цена убыв. ", "Цена воз. ", "Год выпуска "
                                              }), new { @class = "sort" })`А  тут нет значений как их добавить

Comment: Добавил значений

Comment: Eсли будут проблемы сообщите пожалуйста